# How much storage used on my Apple TV 4K?

Tags: appletv, storage

On an Apple TV 4K (or Apple TV HD), how can I find out how much storage (“disk” space) is used by OS, apps etc (for example, if 34 gigs on a 64 gig unit are used by OS, apps, and screen saver videos, that would leave 30 gigs free)?

Background: I'm wondering whether I need a 64 GB model or whether the 32 GB model is enough.

Comment: Not in front of one of my ATV’s right now, but I always buy 32GB. I believe you would need to install a lot of games (not just regular apps) to use more than 32GB. I have probably 15 different streaming video/subscription apps and 10 games or so, no issues. Also, I think they do some kind of intelligent offloading of unused apps if you do install more than the memory directly supports.

Comment: Are you asking how to see storage usage on an Apple TV? It’s in Settings: General, Manage Storage. https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/manage-storage-atvb7760522d/tvos

Comment: @JBallin    I am asking how to tell how much of the Apple TV’s storage is used, and how much is not used. For example, of 34 of 64 gigs is used, that would mean 30 gigs are left unused. I’m surprised to see the Question closed for lack of clarity. **How much disk storage is used/free** is a very simple basic computer question. And no, that Manage Storage panel in Settings shows neither how much is used nor how much is free. It shows a list of space used by each app. Even if I tediously added this up with a calculator, that would not cover OS and screen saver videos.

Comment: I do not have an **Apple TV**, however on an **iPhone** if I go to **Settings** > **General** > **About**, there is **Capacity** and **Available**, so maybe check to see if they exist on **Apple TV** too.